# how to wrap/store the key of TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: .net, xml, cryptography, 3des, symmetric-key

I'm using DES encryption, and I want to store the key of TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.

But the key consists of (Key + IV),

I was trying to save them in an XML file using

```
XmlTextWriter
Convert.ToBase64String(...)
```

but there was an exception due to IV contains invalid characters "=" in XML.

Is there a better way to store symmetric cryptography key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in XML if you put it into a CDATA section using the [WriteCData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writecdata.aspx) method